# How to create a Windows installer on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

I want to create a Windows installer on my Ubuntu server.
Does anybody know which installation creator can be used for that purpose EXCEPT for [NSIS](http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=300326) ?
Thanks !

Comment: What is your understanding of "Windows Installer"?  An installer that runs a Windows or an actual "Windows Installer" (.msi) database that's processed by the "Windows Installer" platform service?   If the former, the windows-installer tag doesn't belong on your question,  if the answer is the latter, NSIS doesn't generate MSI's so it's not relevant anyways.

Comment: @Blender- You want an honest answer?

Comment: @ChristopherPainter - The end result should be an EXE which contains a couple of files. When clicked on the target machine it extracts these files and can afterwards execute them. That's the basic requirements. Preferably I can control the icon of the file, it's properties, compression, etc.

Comment: @Blender - Nothing wrong with it (IMHO) but I need to explore alternative ways.

Comment: removed windows-installer tag for you since it doesn't apply.

Answer (score 1):

I had success with [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net) (using`wine` and windows version of `mono`).